# Mongoose avoide duplicate with find query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm integrating auto complete search but I stuck that how can i avoide duplicate item while search

```
Deal.find({
            title: _keyword
        })
        .distinct("title")
        .select("title")
        .limit(10)
        .exec(function(err, deals) {
            deffered.resolve(deals);
        });
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain more on what you want to achieve? Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: I want to integrate google like auto complete search, i have some deals in my database & some of them have similar name. Now I want if i'm finding some deal with regular expression it should not return duplicate deal.

Comment: Have you tried [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) ?

Comment: Will it solve avoide duplicate result?

Comment: Try it. It may help. If you will show sample data from your db, we may help you in better way.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Deal.distinct('title')
```

see the documentation of distinct:

[doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db-collection-distinct)